# how to convert a char to an object

Tags: java, arraylist, char

The idea is here that I want the user to type in a char that will then be added to an ArrayList of other characters but when I try and add it , eclipse comes up with this error :

> The method add(Character) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (char)

So I was wondering, how can I convert the char to an object?

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: Show us your code. This should be done automatically.

Comment: Which Java version, btw?

Comment: @ankon He's using generics, which I'm pretty sure was released after(or with) auto-boxing.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Character#valueOf()` method:

```
List<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
list.add(Character.valueOf('c'));
```

Comment: This should not be necessary.

Comment: Depending on your warning settings it might be needed: assume some policy that auto-boxing should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: This is not a warning, it is an error. @HotLicks Sure, but it doesn't explain the error. I wanted clarifications from OP.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The good news is that if your answer is right, and the OP tries this, he'll find out very quickly when it tells him that his `Character` is not a `Character`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm almost certain that you've defined your own `Character` class in the same package as the code you are trying to run. Use fully qualified class names to avoid such issues.

Boxing conversion only works from `java.lang.Character` to `char` and vice versa (and other such primitive types to their wrappers). It doesn't work with your custom types. You'll need to convert the `char` yourself if you keep using your own `Character` class.

Comment: Except that ArrayList will reference java.lang.Character, and the OP can't override that.  Since the error message clearly says the method is ArrayList.add(Character), the "Character" being referenced must be java.lang.Character (unless the OP has created his own version of ArrayList).

Comment: @HotLicks How do you figure? If I make a class Character, I can surely make a generic List of them...

Comment: @HotLicks If the `Character` class is in the same package, it will have priority over `java.lang.Character`.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right, if it's a generic.  (%$#@ generics!)

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<Character>();
char character = 'a';
characters.add(character);
```